# Using NumPy in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, pip

I downloaded http://pytools.codeplex.com/ (Python Tools for Visual Studio) so that I could write Python in Visual Studio.

The problem is when I try to use the most basic package "numpy" like so:

```
import numpy
```

It says "**No module named 'numpy'**."

How can I use NumPy and SciPy in Visual Studio?

Note: I am using [Canopy Expres](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/free/)s on another machine which works perfectly; however, I don't want to install it on this machine since I already have Visual Studio installed.

I added the Python 3.3 environment to my Python "solution" by right-clicking Python environments and clicking add an environment. But, after right-clicking my environment and clicking install Python package, I typed in "numpy" and got this error when trying to install it:

```
...
creating build
creating build\src.win32-3.3
creating build\src.win32-3.3\numpy
creating build\src.win32-3.3\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\dom\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Dom\numpy
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Dom\pip\pip.log
'numpy' failed to install. Exit code: 1
```

How can I install NumPy?

Comment: Did you install numpy? It's not "the most basic package" since it's not in the standard library.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to install dependencies via python or through the IDE (Visual Studio, in this case).  Must I do it myself, manually?  Disclaimer:  I'm very new to python development :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/1265154; or, better, with binary installer http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Thanks, but this is getting silly!  I was expecting "install python package" to actually work...  It appears there is a compiler error or something as per https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy/issues/63 I think I am just going to use Canopy Express.  I remember it was pretty awesome for Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a more feature-rich Windows distribution of Python, like [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). It comes with [a boatload of packages](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html) included into the installer. This is quite handy for those who are new to Python, especially when they are using Windows.

**Edit**:

**As of 2020, I would suggest using the `python.org` distribution of Python.** Compiler issues on ms-windows have *finally* been fixed, so a lot of projects now provide binary packages (wheels) for ms-windows. Among others [`numpy`](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files), [`pandas`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files), [`matplotlib`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files), [`pillow`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files), [`Cython`](https://pypi.org/project/Cython/#files) and [`PyNaCl`](https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/#files).

Note that wheel names ending in:

- `win_amd64.whl` are for 64-bit versions of ms-windows, and
- `win32.whl` are for 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks Anaconda looks pretty cool.  I am going to use Canopy Express https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/free/ which is also very cool (and free)!  Someday maybe Microsoft will get their act together with this :)

Comment: @user1477388 Anaconda is also free. It's the add-ons (like optimized math and database libraries) that cost money. Either Anaconda or Canopy Express would be fine. I can sympathize with your plight. I'm used to working with FreeBSD and Linux which come with a host of free tools either installed or easily available. Every time I have to use a Windows box it feels like a barren wasteland in comparison.

Answer (score 35):

In Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition with a Python 2.7 environment, the following worked for me:

Open the Python Environments menu in Solution Explorer, and click on "**Install Python Package...**"

[image]

Then write "**numpy**":

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Two solutions worked for me:

1. Going directly to my Python folder and installing the packages using pip.
2. Creating a virtual environment in my project and installing packages from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

In ***Visual Studio 2022*** just use the "**Solution Explorer**" to install ***NumPy***.

- **Expand** the ***Project*** and then **expand** the ***Python Environments***
- **Right click** on the ***Python installation*** and choose "**Manage Python Packages...**"

[image: Solution Explorer]

- **Type** "**numpy**" in the search field
- **Click** on "**Run command: pip install numpy**"

[image: Python Environment]

Now NumPy should be installed on the Visual Studio Python environment!

***Note** that if the chosen Python environment is:*

- *"Python 3.XX (global default)"

  Then NumPy will be installed on your default Visual Studio
  Python environment,*
- *NOT the (global default)

  Then NumPy will JUST be installed on your current project.*

Answer (score 2):

I actually ran into the same set of problems when trying to use Visual Studio for Python.

I managed to get things to work at the end - please see *[Using Visual Studio 2013 for Python (3.4) with NumPy and SciPy on Windows](https://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/using-visual-studio-2013-for-python-3-4-with-numpy-and-scipy-on-windows/)* for details. Essentially you can either use the installer (if one is available) or use [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) to do the installation.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure C++ Common Tools are installed in Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Setup]

Answer (score 1):

From *[PTVS Installation](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation)*:

> **2. Installing packages individually**
>
> Here are some recommended packages. Generally you want to install packages using `pip` or through the interface in Visual Studio (which uses `pip`), as this will ensure that you get the latest version that will work with your version of Python, as well as any dependencies.
>
> Some packages have complex dependencies and need to be downloaded manually, either from the project's website or from [Christoph Gohlke's package collection](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

I installed `numpy` and `scipy` from these links, and it works perfectly with Visual Studio.

- `numpy` http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/
- `scipy` http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/
- `Matplotlib` http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html
- `Pandas` http://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html

Answer (score 1):

See under Extra in the Visual Studio (Extra-Python-Interactive Window).

It has the ability to switch the interactive console through a different platform/Python version (32-bit, 64-bit, Debug, and Anaconda (which has the NumPy package)).